# WinUi3 display another windows

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

If you use another Window on WinUi3, you will get an Error.
Do you know how now?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: What version of WinUI3 are you using?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  In fact you're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] we can copy to reproduce and debug the problem for ourselves.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating new windows is currently not supported in the stable release (version 0.8.2) of WinUI3.

If you install the latest release of the [experimental channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/experimental-channel#version-10-experimental-100-experimental1) (version 1.0.0-experimental1), you can however create and display new windows like this:

```
var win = new Window();
win.Activate();
```

[How to open a new Window in WinUI 3 for Desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5135)